# How to define holidays for is.holiday() chron package in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `chron`'s `is.holiday()` function, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.  The documentation says to modify the `.Holiday` object with the holidays that you wish to use, but the changes I've made to `.Holiday` don't seem to be detected by `is.holiday()`.  Could someone provide an example of the appropriate way to load holidays?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is non-trivial and probably deserves to be referred to the `chron` maintainer as a bug.

```
library(chron)
library(timeDate)
hlist <- c("CAVictoriaDay","CACanadaDay","CALabourDay")
(ss <- dates(sapply(sapply(hlist,holiday,year=2011),as.Date)))
.Holidays <- ss
```

(Someone who actually works with dates in R more often than I do probably has a more elegant solution for the preceding stuff, without that double-`sapply` thing ...)

But this doesn't change the important thing, which is the version of `Holidays` *in the `chron` namespace*:

```
chron::.Holidays  ## no change
```

The clue is here: [Override a function that is imported in a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254744/override-a-function-that-is-imported-in-a-namespace)

Namespace magic:

```
unlockBinding(".Holidays", as.environment("package:chron"))
assignInNamespace(".Holidays", .Holidays, ns="chron", 
    envir=as.environment("package:chron"))
assign(".Holidays", .Holidays, as.environment("package:chron"))
lockBinding(".Holidays", as.environment("package:chron"))
```

Now look, and it has worked:

```
chron::.Holidays
```

Test it out:

```
yrvec <- seq.Date(as.Date("2011-01-01"),
                    as.Date("2011-12-31"),by="day")
plot(is.holiday(yrvec),axes=FALSE)
axis.Date(side=1,yrvec)
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was significantly more complicated than I expected.

Comment: The solution above is fantastic, and works, with the exception that there seems to an error if hlist includes "GBNewYearsEve"

I've started a new question on that [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777282/in-using-timedate-r-package-i-receive-an-error-when-specifying-gbnewyearseve)

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same thing and found this older post. I didn't need to modify `.Holidays`:

```
library(timeDate);library(chron)
hlist <- c("USChristmasDay","USGoodFriday","USIndependenceDay","USLaborDay",
    "USNewYearsDay","USThanksgivingDay")        
myholidays  <- dates(as.character(holiday(2000:2013,hlist)),format="Y-M-D")

> is.holiday(as.Date("2013-11-28"),myholidays)

[1] TRUE

> chron::.Holidays
  New Years Day     Memorial Day Independence Day        Labor Day     Thanksgiving        Christmas 
    01/01/92         05/25/92         07/04/92         09/07/92         11/26/92         12/25/92
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking a lot about this topic, I found this solution particularly simple using the package RQuantLib, so maybe RQuantLib might be more simple in this regard.

```
install.packages("RQuantLib")
library(RQuantLib)
isBusinessDay(calendar="WeekendsOnly", dates=yourdatesofinterest)
```

You can modify this code with different calendars to add to the weekends different sets of holidays in different countries (below just an example, but they have many more).

```
isBusinessDay(calendar="UnitedStates", dates=yourdatesofinterest)
isBusinessDay(calendar="UnitedStates/Settlement", dates=yourdatesofinterest)
isBusinessDay(calendar="UnitedStates/NYSE", dates=yourdatesofinterest)
isBusinessDay(calendar="Sweden", dates=yourdatesofinterest)
isBusinessDay(calendar="Mexico", dates=yourdatesofinterest)
```

I hope it helps somebody