# Test if a date is a holiday in r

Tags: r, date, time-series, chron

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
9/1/2014 00:00:25  
9/1/2014 00:00:28  
9/1/2014 00:00:40
```

There are many more observations...

I want to create a column that indicates if a date is  a holiday or not , so i used the `is.holiday()` function. This is my code:

```
final_uber_4$is_holiday <- is.holiday(final_uber_4$interv)
```

The problem is that it returnes 0 for all the observations although I know for sure there are holidays in my data set.

Comment: If you'd like to improve your chances of getting a fast answer and avoid downvotes on your question, I'd recommend following StackOverflow question posting guidelines, which includes using correct punctuation, removing salutations (e.g. 'hi' and 'thanks for the help :)') and using correct formatting (e.g. on the dates). I recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using the `is.holiday` function from the `chron` package.  I'd recommend against using that package; the date functions in R have improved since it was written and it isn't needed.

If you want to use `is.holiday`, you need to provide a list of holidays in the format that `chron` is expecting.  This isn't easy; see this question [How to define holidays for is.holiday() chron package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7451354/2554330) from 2016 for a discussion.

But if you're providing the list of holidays, you don't need `is.holiday`.  Just use `%in%`.  For example,

```
holidays <- as.Date(c(NewYears = "2014-01-01", Christmas = "2014-12-25"))
# Add more to the list above...

# Convert your data plus a holiday to POSIXct format:
interv <- as.POSIXct(c("9/1/2014 00:00:25", 
                       "9/1/2014 00:00:28",
                       "9/1/2014 00:00:40",
                       "1/1/2014 00:00:00"), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

# Extract the date:
dates <- as.Date(interv)

# Test if you've got a holiday:
dates %in% holidays
```

This gives me

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

at the end.