# R selective importing from namespaces

Tags: r, namespaces, package

If I'm writing an R package, I can use `importFrom(plyr,colwise)` to selectively import the `colwise()` function into my namespace.  If I'm running code interactively at the command line, is there a way to do likewise?

One crude solution would be to load a package but not import anything, then write a bunch of `foo <- pkg::foo` assignments to manually import, but I can't see how to just load without importing in the first place.

Comment: Maybe some hints in the discussions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254744/  ?   But, what's your objection to loading packages? If there are a couple functions you plan to use a lot, then why not manually import them once and build them into your default environment.

Comment: Loading packages is fine - I just don't want to *import* everything, especially when there are conflicts.  I'd rather just import the things I know I'm going to use.  I've been burned by unexpected imports before, e.g. when a new version of a package adds an import that didn't formerly exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps all I need to do is this (giving it real names instead of `foo` so it can be run)?

```
loadNamespace('zoo')
rollmean <- zoo::rollmean
rollmean.default <- zoo::rollmean.default
```

Any comments about pitfalls of doing so?  I haven't used `loadNamespace()` before.

Comment: If you go this route, you don't even need the `loadNamespace()` call.

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. (If you find differently after trying it out, please let me know!)

Comment: Wow, that's crazy.  I had no idea the `::` syntax triggered an auto-load of the code.  The documentation confirms it too: "The namespace will be loaded if it was not loaded before the call, but the package will not be attached to the search path."

Answer (score 4):

If you find yourself repeatedly wanting to use the same few functions from a package, the cleanest solution might be to create and load a package containing just those functions .

```
## Set up package source directory
dummy <- ""  ## Need one object with which to initiate package skeleton
package.skeleton("dummy", "dummy")

## Clean up the man subdirectory
lapply(dir("dummy/man", full.names=TRUE), file.remove)

## Use NAMESPACE to pull in the functions you want
funs <- c("aaply", "ddply", "adply")
cat(paste0("importFrom(plyr, ", paste(funs, collapse=", "), ")"),
    paste0("export(", paste(funs, collapse=", "), ")"),
    file = "dummy/NAMESPACE",
    sep = "\n")

## install the package
library(devtools)
install("dummy")

## Confirm that it worked
library(dummy)
ls(2)
# [1] "aaply" "adply" "ddply"
environment(aaply)
# <environment: namespace:plyr>
aaply(matrix(1:9, ncol=3), 2, mean)
# 1 2 3 
# 2 5 8
```

Comment: (This seems like overkill to me, but it's interesting to see that it's at least possible.)

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering about a solution like that too.  I would not have discovered this on my own!