# Selectively import functions using regex

Tags: r, namespaces, roxygen2

I am looking to import only a few functions from a package. Based on this [issue](https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/617), I can use `@rawNamespace` to import `except`.

However, what I would like to do is close to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16304858/10323798) answer. I would like to define a regular expression to only import certain functions automatically. I would like to avoid importing an entire package just for a couple of functions.

Example

```
#' My fancy function
#' @rawNamespace import(ggplot2, except = scale_fill_manual)
#' @export

hello_world <- function(){
  print("Hello World!")
}
```

In the above example, I would like to do something like:

```
#' My fancy function
#' @rawNamespace import(ggplot2, include = scale_*)
#' @export

hello_world <- function(){
  print("Hello World!")
}
```

The above example is super basic but I will actually use the imported functions somewhere else. I cannot simply use `::` accessors as I am programmatically getting the functions from the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46098814/10323798) answer, my current workaround is:

```
lapply(Filter(function(x) grepl("scale_", x), getNamespaceExports("ggplot2")),
       utils::getFromNamespace, "ggplot2")
```

The above will allow me to import all `ggplot2` `scale` functions while only necessitating that I specify a `utils` import in the `Description`. However, I think that this may be less ideal since perhaps it requires `ggplot2` or whatever package to be on the `search` path.

This also is flawed because then I need to add names to the list to be able to figure out which function is which.

Comment: There is an `exportPattern`.  Not sure if that works for you

Comment: Looks useful, maybe I need `importPattern` but it seems not to exist?

Comment: that is not there.