# R trace doesn't work correctly inside functions?

Tags: r, trace

`trace` doesn't seem to work correctly inside precompiled functions

For example, in this snippet

```
xx <- 2:7
nu <- seq(-10, 9, length.out = 2001)
op <- par(lab = c(16, 5, 7))
matplot(nu, t(outer(xx, nu, besselI)), type = "l", ylim = c(-50, 200),
        main = expression(paste("Bessel ", I[nu](x), " for fixed ", x,
                                ",  as ", f(nu))),
        xlab = expression(nu))
```

Simple `trace` for `xy.coords` works fine

```
trace(xy.coords)
matplot(nu, t(outer(xx, nu, besselI)), type = "l", ylim = c(-50, 200),
        main = expression(paste("Bessel ", I[nu](x), " for fixed ", x,
                                ",  as ", f(nu))),
        xlab = expression(nu))
# trace: xy.coords
# trace: xy.coords
# trace: xy.coords
# trace: xy.coords
# trace: xy.coords
# trace: xy.coords
# trace: xy.coords
```

But tracing with function doesn't seem to work

```
trace(xy.coords, tracer = quote(cat("test\n")))
# Tracing function "xy.coords" in package "grDevices"
# [1] "xy.coords"
matplot(nu, t(outer(xx, nu, besselI)), type = "l", ylim = c(-50, 200),
        main = expression(paste("Bessel ", I[nu](x), " for fixed ", x,
                                ",  as ", f(nu))),
        xlab = expression(nu))
```

While direct call works fine

```
xy.coords(1:3, 1:2, recycle = TRUE)
# Tracing xy.coords(1:3, 1:2, recycle = TRUE) on entry 
# test
# $x
# [1] 1 2 3
# 
# $y
# [1] 1 2 1
# 
# $xlab
# NULL
# 
# $ylab
# NULL
```

What is going on and what do I need to change that?

**Update** I disable compilation of `grDevices` and other `base` packages, but `trace` still doesn't work correctly. When debugging `matplot`, `xy.coords` appears to be without tracing.

**Update 2** This seems to be related to [Override a function that is imported in a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254744/override-a-function-that-is-imported-in-a-namespace), but after trying everything suggested there with assigning in namespace the traced object, the old one still gets called.

Comment: add `where = matplot` and maybe `print = FALSE` if you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acting on the imports of graphics (where matplot belongs) seems to do the trick:

```
xx <- 2:7
nu <- seq(-10, 9, length.out = 2001)
op <- par(lab = c(16, 5, 7))

trace(xy.coords, tracer = quote(cat("test\n")))

# get the imports env of graphics
nsi <- parent.env(getNamespace('graphics'))

unlockBinding("xy.coords", nsi)
assign('xy.coords', xy.coords, nsi)

matplot(nu, t(outer(xx, nu, besselI)), type = "l", ylim = c(-50, 200),
        main = expression(paste("Bessel ", I[nu](x), " for fixed ", x,
                                ",  as ", f(nu))),
        xlab = expression(nu))


Tracing xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log = log) on entry 
test
Tracing xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) on entry 
test
Tracing xy.coords(x, y) on entry 
test
Tracing xy.coords(x, y) on entry 
test
Tracing xy.coords(x, y) on entry 
test
Tracing xy.coords(x, y) on entry 
test
Tracing xy.coords(x, y) on entry 
test
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize to look into the imports namespace

Comment: @RomanTsegelskyi please explain why simply doing `trace(xy.coords, tracer = quote(cat("test\n")), where = matplot)` wasnt sufficient

Comment: looking at trace() code, it seems that with no tracer arg, the tracing is performed by  .Primitive(".primTrace"), otherwise by methods:::.TraceWithMethods(). Hence two different implementations.