# R - How to add legend title to levelplot saved to a variable?

Tags: r, title, legend, levelplot

I would like to add the title for a legend in a levelplot graph saved to a variable.

For example, this code works:

```
library(lattice)
library(grid)
x = 1:10
y = rep(x,rep(10,10))
x = rep(x,rep(10))
z = x+y  
levelplot(z~x*y, colorkey=list(labels=list(cex=1,font=2,col="brown"),height=1,width=1.4),main=list('b',side=1,line=0.5))
trellis.focus("legend", side="right", clipp.off=TRUE, highlight=FALSE)
grid.text(expression(m^3/m^3), 0.2, 0, hjust=0.5, vjust=1)
trellis.unfocus()
```

But this code, where the same plot is being saved as a variable, does NOT work:

```
p1 <- levelplot(z~x*y, colorkey=list(labels=list(cex=1,font=2,col="brown"),height=1,width=1.4),main=list('b',side=1,line=0.5))
trellis.focus("legend", side="right", clipp.off=TRUE, highlight=FALSE)
grid.text(expression(m^3/m^3), 0.2, 0, hjust=0.5, vjust=1)
trellis.unfocus()
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Adding-title-to-colorkey-td4633584.html looks a lot simpler

Comment: link ^^ died but  i think https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-June/315948.html  is the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but it perhaps offers a change in workflow, where you can add a title to the key using the colorkey arguments.

It involves tweaking the `draw.colorkey` function.

The easiest way is to use `fixInNamespace` interactively

```
fixInNamespace("draw.colorkey", "lattice")
```

at the end of the function change the last few lines to

```
    }
    if (!is.null(key$title)) {
        key.gf <- placeGrob(key.gf, textGrob(key$title, hjust = key$hjust, 
            vjust = key$vjust, gp = key$gp), row = key$row, col = key$column)
    }
    if (draw) 
        grid.draw(key.gf)
    key.gf
}
```

Save and close, and you can then use as shown below.

---

However, you may not be able to do this interactively, so it can also be done as

```
library(lattice)
library(grid)

# Amend key function
# Hopefully a nicer way to do this!
mykey <- draw.colorkey

body(mykey)[28:30] <- list(
quote(
  if(!is.null(key$title)){
      key.gf <- placeGrob(key.gf,
                      textGrob(key$title,hjust=key$hjust, vjust=key$vjust, gp=key$gp),
                          row=key$row, col=key$column)
  }),
body(mykey)[[28]], 
body(mykey)[[29]])

# Assign to namespace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254744/override-a-function-that-is-imported-in-a-namespace
unlockBinding("draw.colorkey", as.environment("package:lattice"))
assign("draw.colorkey", mykey, "package:lattice")
unlockBinding("draw.colorkey", getNamespace("lattice"))
assign("draw.colorkey", mykey, getNamespace("lattice"))
```

You can then pass a key title, specifying the position

```
# Draw plot
x = 1:10
y = rep(x,rep(10,10))
x = rep(x,rep(10))
z = x+y 
p <- levelplot(z~x*y, 
              colorkey=list(labels=list(cex=1, font=2, col="brown"),
                            height=1, width=1.4,
                            title=expression(m^3/m^3), row=3, column=1, vjust=2),
               main=list('b',side=1,line=0.5))


p
```

Which produces

[image]