# Increase colorkey title font size on levelplot

Tags: r, title, legend, font-size, levelplot

I am trying to increase the title for a legend in a levelplot graph saved to a variable. I've used code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874897/r-how-to-add-legend-title-to-levelplot-saved-to-a-variable) to add a colorkey legend title to a levelplot graph that is saved to a variable.

```
library(lattice)
library(grid)

# Amend key function
# Hopefully a nicer way to do this!
mykey <- draw.colorkey

body(mykey)[28:30] <- list(
quote(
  if(!is.null(key$title)){
      key.gf <- placeGrob(key.gf,
                      textGrob(key$title,hjust=key$hjust, vjust=key$vjust, gp=key$gp),
                          row=key$row, col=key$column)
  }),
body(mykey)[[28]], 
body(mykey)[[29]])

# Assign to namespace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254744/override-a-function-that-is-imported-in-a-namespace
unlockBinding("draw.colorkey", as.environment("package:lattice"))
assign("draw.colorkey", mykey, "package:lattice")
unlockBinding("draw.colorkey", getNamespace("lattice"))
assign("draw.colorkey", mykey, getNamespace("lattice"))
# Draw plot
x = 1:10
y = rep(x,rep(10,10))
x = rep(x,rep(10))
z = x+y 
p <- levelplot(z~x*y, 
              colorkey=list(labels=list(cex=1, font=2, col="brown"),
                            height=1, width=1.4,
                            title=expression(m^3/m^3), row=3, column=1, vjust=2),
               main=list('b',side=1,line=0.5))


p
```

But I would like to increase the font size of the legend title. I tried specifying `gp=gpar(fontsize=14)` and `gp=gpar(cex=9)` after the `vjust` argument, but the font size doesn't change. Not entirely sure how the `gp` argument works, I assumed it follows `grid.text` and takes from `gpar` but it doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the title font size using `cex`, for example:

```
levelplot(z~x*y, 
              colorkey=list(labels=list(cex=1, font=2, col="brown"),
                            height=1, width=1.4,
                            title=expression(m^3/m^3), row=3, column=1, vjust=2),
               main=list(label='b',side=1,line=0.5, cex=10))
```

Answer (score 1):

in [your Theme](https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/#themes)
myTheme$fontsize$text<-10
or whatever size you want