# Adding Legends to Level Plots

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, lattice

I am trying to make "Level Plots" in R, and I am following the instructions from here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lattice/versions/0.10-10/topics/levelplot

```
library(lattice)
x <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length = 100)
y <- seq(pi/4, 5 * pi, length = 100)
r <- as.vector(sqrt(outer(x^2, y^2, "+")))
grid <- expand.grid(x=x, y=y)
grid$z <- cos(r^2) * exp(-r/(pi^3))
levelplot(z~x*y, grid, cuts = 50, scales=list(log="e"), xlab="",
          ylab="", main="Weird Function", sub="with log scales",
          colorkey = FALSE, region = TRUE)
```

[image]

Is there any way to add a legend to this plot? There does not seem to be any indication of a legend option in the "rdocumentation".

I found a similar post over here that shows how to add a legend: [R - How to add legend title to levelplot saved to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36874897/r-how-to-add-legend-title-to-levelplot-saved-to-a-variable)

But this seems to be a complicated way to add a legend.

Is there really no simple way to add a legend to this level plot?

Comment: Does `colorkey = TRUE`do what you want?

Comment: @Marcinthebox : thank you! this has fixed the problem! Would you like to enter a full answer so that future readers can see how to solve the problem? Or would you like me to do it for you? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No problem - I have added the example as an answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to assign `colorkey = TRUE`:

```
levelplot(z~x*y, grid, cuts = 50, scales=list(log="e"), xlab="",
          ylab="", main="Weird Function", sub="with log scales",
          colorkey = TRUE, region = TRUE)
```

[image]