# Override a function that is not exported by namespace in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-environment

In R, there appears to be a way to override functions within a namespace (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254744/override-a-function-that-is-imported-in-a-namespace)). I'm wondering, is it possible to override a function from a package *that was not exported*.

For example, `ggplot_build()` is exported by `ggplot2`. I can override it using the following code example:

```
library(ggplot2)    
g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg)) + geom_density()

my.ggplot_build <- function(plot) print(class(plot))

ggplot_build(g)
# Plot rendered

unlockBinding("ggplot_build", as.environment("package:ggplot2"))
assign("ggplot_build", my.ggplot_build, as.environment("package:ggplot2"))
lockBinding("ggplot_build", as.environment("package:ggplot2"))

ggplot_build(g)
# [1] "gg"     "ggplot"
```

However, is there a way to override the `print.ggplot()` function that is not exported by `ggplot`?

I can access unexported functions via triple `:` such as `ggplot2:::print.ggplot()`. Is there a way to override these functions?

Comment: look at `fixInNamespace` or `assignInNamespace`. Do these do what you want?

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick:
`assignInNamespace("print.ggplot", my.print.ggplot, ns="ggplot2", pos="package:ggplot2")`