# Trigger a reaction after change of textOutput() in shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, reactive

I am trying to use [JohnCoene/marker](https://github.com/johncoene/marker) package to highlight sections of text in a shiny app. My intend is to first generate the text using some server logic and display it with `textOutput`. However, I am struggeling with how to **trigger** the `marker` **after the text appeared on the website**. Putting it in the same `observeEvent()` does not work.

Here is my reprex

```r
# remotes::install_github("johncoene/marker")
library(shiny)
library(marker)

ui <- fluidPage(
  use_marker(),
  actionButton("click", "click"),
  textOutput("text_to_mark")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
   observeEvent(input$click, 
                {
                  output$text <- renderText("My house is yellow")
                })
  # observeEvent() below does not work. This is just for illustration
  observeEvent(input$text_to_mark,
               {
                 marker <- marker$new("#text_to_mark.shiny-text-output.shiny-bound-output")
                 marker$
                   unmark()$ # unmark all before we mark
                   mark("My house")
               })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

For illustration: I can get the marker to work, by adding a second button as in the code below, but I am look for a solution where it gets triggered when the text appears.

```r
# remotes::install_github("johncoene/marker")
library(shiny)
library(marker)

ui <- fluidPage(
  use_marker(),
  actionButton("click", "click"),
  textOutput("text_to_mark"),
  actionButton("mark", "Mark!")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$click, 
               {
                 output$text_to_mark <- renderText("My house is yellow")
               })
  observeEvent(input$mark,
               {
                 marker <- marker$new("#text_to_mark.shiny-text-output.shiny-bound-output")
                 marker$
                   unmark()$ # unmark all before we mark
                   mark("My house")
               })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen on DOM changes with javascript: [Is there a JavaScript / jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener).

When a change happens you can check if your target element has text:

```
  hasText = document.getElementById("text_to_mark").innerHTML != ""
```

Note that i assume that your element has the id "text_to_mark".

The result you can "send to R" with

```
  Shiny.onInputChange("hasText", hasText);
```

On the R side you will know if the element has text via listening on `input$hasText`.

So you can add:

```
observeEvent(input$hasText,{
   ...
})
```

The javascript you can add to your app with `tags$script(jsCode)` or use `shinyjs`.

**A reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)
library(marker)

jsCode <- '
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
  console.log(mutations, observer);
  hasText = document.getElementById("text_to_mark").innerHTML != ""
  Shiny.onInputChange("hasText", hasText);
});

observer.observe(document, {
  subtree: true,
  attributes: true
});
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  use_marker(),
  tags$script(jsCode),
  actionButton("click", "click"),
  textOutput("text_to_mark"),
  actionButton("mark", "Mark!")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$click, {
                 output$text_to_mark <- renderText("My house is yellow")
               })
  observeEvent(input$hasText,{
                 marker <- marker$new("#text_to_mark.shiny-text-output.shiny-bound-output")
                 marker$
                   unmark()$ # unmark all before we mark
                   mark("My house")
               })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note that this only works on the first appearance of the text. If you also want to listen for changes of the text, one could send the text to R instead and check on the R side if the text was updated. Not sure if it is needed here.

Comment: Indeed I want to listen to changes of the text. I have changed it to something like `Text = document.getElementById("text_to_mark").innerHTML`. Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Listening on DOM changes is one option, but your approach already shows that there is a pure shiny (non-custom-JS) solution, it only takes one click more, so the question is how to do it with only one click. I suggest using [`invalidateLater`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/invalidateLater.html) and wrap it in an `if` statement to prevent it from running over and over again like seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244988/shiny-how-to-stop-processing-invalidatelater-after-data-was-abtained-or-at-th).

The trick is to run your marker calls in an `observe` statement. Include the `invalidateLater` here and wrap it in an `if` condition with a counter which counts how many times the statement has been executed. Play around with the number of milliseconds and counts, in my case it works fine with `if(isolate(val$cnt) < 1)` and `invalidateLater(1000)`. Don't forget to wrap your counter in an `isolate` otherwise it will get stuck in a loop.

Note also that `input$click` not only writes the text into a reactiveValue but also resets the counter `val$cnt` to `0` so that you can use the `invalidateLater` again on a new text. The same procedure will help you if you want to update your text using an observeEvent or the like. Just make sure to also reset the counter to 0 and the highlighting works on your new text part.

```
# remotes::install_github("johncoene/marker")
library(shiny)
library(marker)

ui <- fluidPage(
  use_marker(),
  actionButton("click", "click"),
  textOutput("text_to_mark")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  val <- reactiveValues(cnt = 0,
                        text = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$click, {
    val$text <- "My house is yellow"
    val$cnt <- 0

  })


  observe({
    if(isolate(val$cnt) < 1) {
      invalidateLater(1000)
    }

    marker <- marker$new("#text_to_mark.shiny-text-output.shiny-bound-output")
    marker$
      unmark()$ # unmark all before we mark
      mark("My house")

    val$cnt = isolate(val$cnt) + 1
    })

  output$text_to_mark <-renderText({
    val$text
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thanks for providing an alternative solution. I prefer the DOM variant over `invalidateLater`. I find it more readable &not depending on some arbitrary timing.